# How to get previous month value from a given month value as an integer parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL server and i am trying to get the value of the previous month (just `int` not `date`) when i have current month as parameter.
For example: how to get `current-month - 1` when `current-month = 1` (january)?

Sorry if it is an obvious question.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by using [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT @prev_month = CASE WHEN @current_month = 1 THEN 12 ELSE @current_month - 1 END
```

Comment: I was hoping to get it dynamicly , is there any datetime function that can help?

Comment: @inna If both your input and output are INT, not sure why you need use datetime function. The answer I have is dynamic, with parameter current_month as input, it will give you previous month INT value